# Generating models with CoreML in Sonoma slowed significantly compared to Ventura, what has changed?

Tags: macos, clang, coreml, macos-sonoma

I have accidentally updated to Sonoma, and found my CoreML models are generating nearly 7x slower since the update. I also no longer get the verbose information in terminal (i.e time taken per cycle, deviation from actual result etc). This is using xcode and swift developed for MacOS.

The M1 laptop I am using is also under considerably less stress (i.e it is no longer getting warm, battery life much improved when running the code). This significantly decreased performance happens whether connected to power or not.  Low power mode is not on.

Is there a flag I need to set to increase performance, a button I need to press, any suggestions would be helpful. I noted that there is a new Game Mode, is this linked to this decrease in performance?

Please note this is 24hr+ since the update, so it should no longer be affected by any usual background tasks after an upgrade.

Just to note, I am using something similar to this to build the model

```
let params_boosted = MLBoostedTreeRegressor.ModelParameters(maxIterations: 10000) 

let model = try MLBoostedTreeRegressor(trainingData: trainingdata, targetColumn: columntopredict, parameters: params_boosted)
```

on an M1 MacBook Pro 16Gb. Models are literally taking 7x longer to build.

I have run the same code in both Ventura and Sonoma Mac OS'.  I expected the code to run at the same speed, and instead it runs 7x slower.